# how to pass query string on button click when data retrieve from database

Tags: webforms

I make a method for data retrieving from database. showing data in repeater using button inside repeater. I want to pass query string on button click with passing id.

```cs
if(e.CommandName=="detail")
{
    Response.Redirect("cardetail.aspx?id=" +carid);
}
```

It's not working

Comment: Describe "not working"

Comment: This is a correct redirect are you doing this in your code-behind of the recipient page: `string id = Request.QueryString["id"];`?